# Selecting Rows in Pandas within a certain value radius

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first question so I don't know how to phrase it properly.
My question is that I have two lists and I need to select values or the index of said values of the first list within a certain region/radius of the second list. For example, I have:

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]
b = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9] 
radius = 0.3
```

And as a result I want to extract the values from "a" and get an output of the values like so:

```
1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10
```

To be more precise, I have a large .csv file with which I use pandas to read the columns and I want to create a new .csv file with only the values or index of said values in with the conditions are met.

(I don't think the data of these .csv files is important at the moment, but I will upload them if necessary)

Comment: on your expected result, is that the value or the index of the said value?

Comment: @Alex if the data is from csv file, number counts of each column is different?

Comment: @AmriRasyidi For this example, those are the values I'd like to obtain

Comment: @liming sorry, but I do not understand your question

Comment: @AlexP length of a, b are different now. usually for pandas dataframe, length of columns are same. So I want to know if the length of columns are different or not in your csv file. if it is the same, there is an easy way but if not, you should do hard coding.

Comment: @liming unfortunately, my csv files have different lengths. one has over 100,000 rows and the other a bit over 10,000

Comment: @AlexP Are you ready to type hard coding?

Comment: @liming if it must be done, then yes. I'm ready

Comment: @MohammadSaad I’ve rejected your edit because it used inappropriate styling (backticks are intended for *code* (and file paths), not for emphasis) and the other changes didn’t objectively improve the question; they were mostly subjective, editorial edits.

Comment: @AlexP Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a_df = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0], columns=['a'])
b = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9] 
radius = 0.3

expanded_b = [(b_value-radius, b_value+radius) for b_value in b]
mask_a = a_df['a'].apply(lambda a_value: any([b_min <= a_value <= b_max for b_min, b_max in expanded_b]))
# use mask_a to mask a
filtered_a_df = a_df[mask_a] ## changed to dataframe a instead of list a
filtered_a_df['a'].astype(int).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, however it is inefficient.

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0]
b = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9] 
radius = 0.3
gdlist=[]
for itera in a:
    for ele in [f for f in b if (itera>= (f-radius) and itera<= (f+radius))]:
        gdlist.append(itera)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I think this code is the fastest way for operation.

```
// Let df as your csv file.
base_list = df['a']
compare_list = df['b']
radius = 0.3

base_list.sort()
compare_list.sort()

idx = 0
result_list = []
for i in range(len(compare_list)):
   for j in range(idx, len(base_list)):
      if compare_list[i] - radius <= base_list[j] <= compare_list[i] + radius:
         result_list.append(base_list[j])
         idx = j
         break

print(result_list)
```